# Resume from point-of-failure in Copy activity Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Assume that I'm trying to copy 1000 records in a table from a database to a Azure SQL DB/Synapse using ADF Copy activity. if the Copy activity fails after copying 600 records, is it poosible to re-run/restart the pipeline such that the Copy activity avoids copying alreday copied records( 600 records which were copied in earlier run) and resume copy operation from remaining 400 records ?

Answer (score 3):

[image]You will have to add a custom script in COPY activity to check the destination and then take only those records from source which are not available in destination.

You can store new records in a temp table and then insert the destination table using the temp table.

Thanks!

Comment: @Scarface: If this answer helped then can you mark it as an answer, so that others from community can get a benefit from this, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using watermark technique , since you have SQL as source its should workout . Use a lookup activity with get the max of the table primary key( on the destinatioin side )  . Once you have a that info create a SQL script to pull in the data from the Source table but add the filter
eg

```
SELECT  from your table 
WHERE   pkId  > '@{activity('Get WaterMark').output.firstrow.pkid}'
```

This should do the trick.